# Remove LCD Stand for Wall Mounting - FSM-270YG

Tags: display, lcd

Based on Jeff Atwood's [post on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/the-ips-lcd-revolution.html), I ordered one of these monitors, and I've been absolutely loving it.  However, I recently (i.e. today) took the next step in monitor-y goodness and fastened the sucker to an articulated wall mount.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to remove the stand.  The flat portion comes off with a single screw, but the leg it fastens to has no apparent method of removing it.

Has anyone figured out a trick for removing these, so they don't just stick out below the screen?  Should I remove the screws from the backside of the screen, and look for an internal connection to remove?  Or just give up and live with it?  (After all, it's a great display, it's floating in the air in front of me, and the stand leg is only a minor annoyance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arm is mounted from the inside by two screws.  In order to get to them, you'll need to remove the 4 screws on the back side along the bottom.  This will free up the face plate which you can pry off- GENTLY- by slipping a razor blade or flat head screwdriver inside of the seam.  There are several tabs where the plastic is locked into place.  Too much force and you'll break something.

Remove the front face with the screen facing up.  You'll see that the LCD component has a metal bracket kept in place by four tabs which are a part of the outer casing, two on each side.  You can use a screwdriver to gently pry them out.

With the monitor free, gently slide it until the metal mounting plate is exposed.  Only slide it so that you can access the screws and no more, and further and you might detach or even break the ribbons.

Unscrew the plate.  The inside plate will be free as well as the mounting arm underneath.

Gently reassemble: make sure the LCD is snapped into the 4 mounting tabs, and then replace the outer face until all it's tabs are snapped into place and there is no gap in the seam.

Turn over, replace the screws, and you should be good to go.

(I have just completed this process myself without incident or blemish, and the monitor is now mounted to my wall, looking fine.)

Comment: Sounds like a real gamble!

Comment: Not really; it was surprisingly easy. Also easy, replacing the stand when I took it off the arm a few years later.